# In iOS 11 , UIViewController's transitionFromViewController never calls its completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios11

Starting in iOS 11, `UIViewController`'s `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` method appears to not call its completion block anymore.

Sample code snippet below:

```
[self addChildViewController:toVC];

[fromVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

[self transitionFromViewController:fromVC
toViewController:toVC
duration:0.4
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
animations:^{}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Completion called"); // this completion is never executed
}];
```

This is causing me all kinds of issues in getting my views to transition and animate correctly. Has anyone else run into this behavior, and/or discovered a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I wasn't explicitly adding `toVC.view` as a subview to `self.view` after adding `toVC` as a child view controller to `self`. Odd that this behaves differently in iOS 11 vs. previous versions, but this did the trick:

```
[self addChildViewController:toVC];
[self.view addSubview:toVC.view]; // This line is what is needed

[fromVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

[self transitionFromViewController:fromVC
toViewController:toVC
duration:0.4
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
animations:^{}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Completion called");
}];
```

Comment: I can confirm that adding the view manually helps when the completion block is not called. In my case it is only necessary when the new view controller has a collection view with a refreshControl. As soon as I remove the refreshControl the completion block gets called nevertheless. Very strange.

Comment: @Klaas that matches my scenario, although I never would have guessed it would be that specific of a corner case. Very strange behavior indeed.